# How to conditionally assign attribute in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
      <span [class.is-awesome]="InputElement.value='yes'">
         Is Is Awesome?
      </span>
      <input type="text" #InputElement (keyup)="0" )>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['src/css/component.css']
})

export class MyComponentComponent {
  name='Muhammad Bilal'
}
```

Error:

> TS2345:Argument of type '{ selector: string; template: string; yes:
>   string; styleUrls: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '{ selector?: string; inputs?: string[]; outputs?: string[];
>   properties?: string[]; events?: strin...'. Object literal may only
>   specify known properties, and 'ye

'I dont know Why it give error when I write 'yes''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular 2 if you are checking for conditions you need to use `===`. And here in your code you have used `"="` that will assign the value `'yes'` to `InputElement.value` which is why you are getting this error.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
      <span [class.is-awesome]="InputElement.value==='yes'">
         Is Is Awesome?
      </span>
      <input type="text" #InputElement (keyup)="0" )>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['src/css/component.css']
})

export class MyComponentComponent {
  name='Muhammad Bilal'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving Error Because you are assigning variable `InputElement.value='yes'`,
Its should be `InputElement.value==='yes'`

```
 <span [class.is-awesome]="InputElement.value==='yes'">
     Is Is Awesome?
 </span>
```